# Google Places API get coordinates

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I have a city place ID, but I need to get latitude and longitude from it.

My method was to let the user search for a place name, hit the API to get a list of suggestions, and when the user selects a single choice, hit the API again to get latitude and longitude.

I can get the place ID, but I can't find anywhere in the API to grab the longitude and latitude from it.

Developing for iOS, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `lookupPlaceId` method of `GMSPlacesClient`. See [Get Place By Id](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details#get-place) for more details.